# Color profiles in videos

Tags: color-correction, metadata

Does the AV-Kit of macOS use the color profiles that may be in the metadata of video files of some formats such as MP4? I am the manual author for GraphicConverter from lemkesoft and need to explain the usage of color profiles in pictures (what I konw about) and video (what is new to me). So I do not need help in a certain work situation but instead background knowledge.

Comment: Please don't take conversation off post and into email or offsite. Also, can you clarify what application you are running on macOS

Comment: I do not envy your position or the task set before you. Good luck, and Godspeed. https://xkcd.com/1882/